# Replacing SSD to check if works

Tags: ssd

I am not sure if this is the place for this question, sorry if not.

My friend has a hardware problem and wants to check if there exists a problem with his SSD.

He wanted to replace the SSD on my computer to see if there is any problem,
 but I believe it is not possible because the hardware is completely different.
 (cannot just plug-in and hope it works, right?)

**Question**
Is there anything that might go wrong;
if we replace my SSD with his SSD on my computer,
re-install Windows 10 (I am using Ubuntu 18.04),
and after we check his SSD, plug my own SSD back.

Thanks for help, I can provide any information that might be useful.
I am not really sure what might be important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a `Computer Hardware Service Manager` with over 30 years experience, I'd say don't do this. The risk of taking a working computer (yours), and breaking it, are too high... especially if we're talking laptop.

If you have a desktop, then their SSD could be connected to a second SATA port (with the appropriate cables), and that would be fine.

Rather, tell the friend to check the SSD's SMART Data log, and to run the SMART diagnostic tests, both by using the `Disks` application or `smartmontools` (or Windows equivalents), and check `/var/log/syslog*` (or the appropriate Windows log files), on their own computer.

Answer (score 4):

Generally that does work yes. I have done it 30. 40 times now. Only thing to do is to remove 3rd party drivers if those are different. So nvidia driver if graphics card is another brand and the NIC driver if another model.

Comment: Thank you. Probably everything is different, he has a gaming laptop and I do have ultrabook. I am not sure if I understood correctly, do I need to remove those drivers before installation and re-install once I plug my SSD back?

Comment: @Jo' No, not yours. But if the other one has Windows it may not boot and if repaired for yours, when back at your friend's another repair will probably be needed.

Comment: @Jo' yes but 1 thing: we only supply support for official Ubuntu. And you can check an ssd in Ubuntu just as fine, or probably even better, than on other operating systems